# Is a questionnaire with a systematically missing item still usable for analysis?

Tags: missing-data

Due to a glitch a single item of a validated questionnaire was not submitted to the participants. Instead of having 20 questions, only 19 were submitted. The literature about the questionnaire tells that the score range should be between 0 an 80, with a cut-point score between 31 and 33. Now, however, the range is between 0 and 76, with a supposed proportional cut-point score between 29 and 32 (rounded).

The questions:

1. Is the data still usable?
2. If yes, how can/should it be handled?

We didn't find any answer in the literature (perhaps because we were not using the proper keywords).

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear about your glitch. I'm not sure about the answer, but I suppose it would depend on a few questions.

A. What is this questionnaire going to be used for? Diagnosis? Research analysis? Medical treatment? I would definitely not use it for any diagnostic criteria that had actionable impact on your participants. For a peer-reviewed paper, that depends on the field, I suppose. It's probably best practice to disclose the glitch in your paper, even if you do end up using the data.

B. How important is to you that the questionnaire be validated? Can you just treat it as an "unvalidated" questionnaire instead? Any questionnaire can be administered in any situation, but you would probably lose the "validation" status if one of the items was consistently missing.

C. How hard is it to go back and ask your participants to fill out the missing item? Impossible? Difficult? Easy? If the latter, perhaps you can just ask them to fill out the missing item, or the entire questionnaire again? Does it matter for the questionnaire at hand that all items be filled out at the same time?

So long as you're not using the questionnaire for diagnostics or any treatment decision (as mentioned in your comment), you can proceed with the research analysis as per usual, and make sure to disclose the erroneously missing data in the paper (e.g. in a footnote or Research Limitations section).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for the late reply. Below, the answers to your questions:
A. The questionnaire would have been used for research analysis. No actionable impact on any participant. It was/is indeed intended for a peer-reviewed paper.
B. Well, I guess that it is always better to use genuine material rather than truncated one. But it is true that it could be used as an "unvalidated" questionnaire. I haven't thought about that (in fact I did not think it was possible).
C. Impossible to go back to the participants. Unfortunately.

Comment: @pdeli Happy to help. In that case, I would proceed with the analysis as per usual, just make sure to disclose the erroneously missing data in the paper (e.g. in a footnote or Research Limitations section). Editing above. If this answers your question, I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer! Best of luck.

Comment: Sure, however, can I ask you if by any chance you have some references? I would gladly add them in your answer.

Comment: @pdeli No references, just my own common sense. Sorry.